# Extracting powers of a sum

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, number-theory, number-representation, number-bases

Given a sum in the form

```
Sum[n^k, {k, kl}]
```

for some natural `n` and natural list `kl`, is it possible to extract the values of `kl`? In other words, I want to know if a sum of the form $ \sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i} $ uniquely determines the tuple $(k_1,...,k_n)$ (up to permutations). This seems true due to the uniqueness of base-$n$ representation, but I am not sure how to implement a function to extract the tuple $(k_1,...,k_n)$. Any ideas?

**My attempt:** Following the [discussion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153197/does-sum-i-1n-nk-i-determines-k-1-k-n), I tried to use `BaseForm`. If we assume $\{k_i\}$ are different, then, as an example,

```
n = 3;
kl = {1, 2, 3};
BaseForm[Sum[n^k, {k, kl}], n]
```

yields $1110_3$ which tells me that `kl = {1, 2, 3}` (in no particular order). How can I produce this list from `BaseForm`? Alternatively, is there a way to transform the representation $1110_3$ into the list `{1, 1, 1, 0}`?

Also, in the case where $\{k_i\}$ are all the same, we may simply take

```
ConstantArray[Log[n, Sum[n^k, {k, kl}]] - 1, n]
```

Could a straightforward computation for both cases (equal $\{k_i\}$ and not) be done? Perhaps using base $n+1$ instead?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention. The length of `kl` must be exactly `n`. Apologies to whoever started working on this without this assumption.

Comment: @JimB That works, given you know the list, correct? The idea is to not rely on the list. In general, I do not know its values, but I know the sum has that specific shape for some list of powers.

Comment: Yes, but I am writing it in that way (poorly, perhaps), just to compute something in my example. In general, I can take `S` as any sum which I know can be written in that format (where `kl` is unknown), and apply `BaseForm[S, n]` to extract the uniquely defined powers. In other words, I am just confirming that I do get that list, as I would expect. I am wondering if I can do this more straightforwardly by looking at the $n+1$ case, for example. The way it is written seems a bit redundant, I agree, but if you look at the linked question on MathSE, it perhaps becomes clearer.

Comment: @JimB Oh! You just reminded me of an important thing that I forgot to mention. The length of `kl` must be exactly `n`! Apologies, I will edit the question to add this. With this, the case `kl = {1, 2, 2, 2, 2}` is not valid.

Comment: OK.  Just one more:  So for a given integer $m$, you're looking for an $n$ and $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ such that $m=\sum_{i=1}^n n^{k_i}$ and hoping there is just one solution?

Comment: Yes, phrased differently, I think that is equivalent to what I am asking.

Comment: If you are requiring that all $k_i>0$, then the value 1007 presents a problem.  No value of $n$ results in all $k_i>0$.  For example, `IntegerDigits[1007, #] & /@ {4, 5, 6}` results in `{{3, 3, 2, 3, 3}, {1, 3, 0, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 5, 5}}`.  So are you searching for the smallest value of $n$ that results in no more than $n$ positive digits?  That would make a value like 7 result in $n=7$.  (I'm trying to understand what restrictions are necessary to result in a unique result.  And I've deleted all but one of my previous comments because you've clarified all of that.)

Answer (score 5):

Use IntegerDigits instead of BaseForm.

```
(* some prior computations... *)
n = 3;
kl = {1, 2, 3}; 
value = Sum[n^k, {k, kl}];
```

Now, assuming that you know what n was used,

```
IntegerDigits[value, 3]
(* returns {1, 1, 1, 0} *)
```

**Edit**
I'm still not sure I entirely get the second part, but if the goal is to reconstruct the "exponent list" (we've been using the variable `kl` for this), then maybe this does what you want:

```
ToExponentList[base_, num_] := 
  Flatten[
    MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2 - 1, #1] &, Reverse@IntegerDigits[num, base]]]
```

(probably a cleaner way to do this, but does this at least produce the correct behavior?)

Proof:

```
ToExponentList[3, Sum[3^k, {k, {1, 2, 3}}]] == {1, 2, 3}
ToExponentList[10, Sum[10^k, {k, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}}]] == {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}
```

**Edit 2**

```
ToWolfeList[base_Integer, num_Integer] :=
  With[
    {digits = IntegerDigits[num, base]},
    Which[
      1 == Total[digits], ConstantArray[Length@digits - 2, base],
      base != Total[digits], NullWolfeList[],
      True, Flatten[MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2 - 1, #1] &, Reverse@digits]]]]
```

It seems like if the sum of the digits does not equal the base, then there is no solution (so I return a NullWolfeList[]). If there is just a digit 1, then we construct a constant array of the appropriate value. Otherwise, we fall back to my previous implementation, which still feels too awkward, but I haven't thought of anything better without resorting to computing logs or some such.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about `IntegerDigits`. However, that fails when `kl = {3, 3, 3}`, for example. Any way to include the cases when `kl` is a constant array? I have my approach, but I was wondering if I could get all at once.

Comment: yeah, I don't understand that part of your question.

Comment: Well, essentially, I want to avoid needing to test whether the value of the sum is a power of `n`. Because, if it is, then `kl` is a constant array, and the solution with `BaseForm` or `IntegerDigits` does not work. In that case, I compute the logarithm like I mentioned. This is a minor thing, but perhaps using a higher base, like `n+1`, could hint at a straightforward bijection between the sum values and the list of powers, `kl`.

Comment: Please see the edit! It was obvious from the mathematical description, but just in case.

Comment: okay, I had just glossed over the fact that n was a constraint on the number of terms in the sum. See edit #2 to my answer.